# Using 3rd party libraries with Pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, scikit-learn, outliers

I have been working with PYOD library of python and have been using LOF, LOCI and CBLOF algorithms. Now I want to move to use Pyspark. I have done some RnD on pyspark MLlib. However, I have not found Implementation of LOF, LOCI or CBLOF in Pyspark. I want to know following:

1. Do Pyspark has LOF, LOCI, CBLOF implementation in it?
2. If not for question 1, How can I integrate PyOD library algorithms with pyspark. So i can do preprocessing of data using PySpark and train using algorithms implemented in PyOD.

Please share if there is some reference. Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those algorithms are unfortunately not available on Spark MLlib, The only way you probably can use (not really effective though, even if it works) is via UDF https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.udf.html?highlight=udf#pyspark.sql.functions.udf

Comment: Thank You. I have used Spark for preprocessing while for machine learning algorithms I am using implementations in PyOD and Sklearn.